# Calling another column using a lambda in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I am examining the [NYC MVA](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/Motor-Vehicle-Collisions-Crashes/h9gi-nx95) dataset. I rewrote the `CRASH TIME` column by combining `CRASH DATE` and `CRASH TIME`:

```
df['CRASH TIME'] = (df['CRASH DATE'] + ' ' + df['CRASH TIME']).apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
df = df.drop('CRASH DATE', axis=1)
```

I have a string with 24 hour data from a sunrise/sunset [API](https://sunrise-sunset.org/api). I'm trying to extract the sunrise and sunset data and turn it into a datetime object.

I wrote a function to perform the API call:

```
def get_sunrise_sunset(sun, date):
    '''
    get sunrise/sunset information
    '''
    api_link = 'https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400&date={}'.format(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    r = requests.get(api_link)
    time = r.json()['results'][sun][:-3]
    if sun == 'sunset':
        time = '1' + str(int(time[0])+2) + time[1:]
    dt_time = dt.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S').time()
    return dt_time
```

I now intend to apply this function over the dataset, creating new columns called `SUNRISE` and `SUNSET`. I've attempted to do this with the following `apply()`:

```
df['SUNRISE'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_sunrise_sunset(sun='sunrise', date=x['CRASH TIME']), axis=1)
```

Unfortunately, this seems to have stalled--I left it running all night long, and it still wasn't done 12 hours later. I'm assuming it's due to an incorrectly written `lambda`-`apply()`. How do I correctly implement this?

Comment: Does the API have a query limit (e.g., the number of requests per second or the number of requests per day)?

Comment: @It_is_Chris I ran the code on a `df.sample()` dataframe; it took 450 ms. Extrapolating that to 1.7 million records and it will take over 8 days to run. Turns out it was working and it was just taking stupidly long. Looks like you were right about the speed.